# How can I get the current path in Dash?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am trying to get the current path of the URL in order do to a filter, but when I call `dcc.Location.pathname` don't get the URL.

Any idea about how can get it?

I tried to with `print(Input('url', 'pathname'))` but dosen't work too.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use `Input('url', 'pathname')` as the input to a callback and build your filter there.

Something like:

```py
@app.callback(
    Output('my-output', 'children'),
    [Input('url', 'pathname')])
def callback_func(pathname):
    # here you can use the pathname however, just like a normal function input
    print(pathname)
```

Comment: this don't print anything

Comment: Do you have `dcc.Location(id='url')` in your layout? It printed correctly for me when I ran it locally.